# accessing protected variable in php

Tags: php

I have created protected variable in php and want to use in php function within same class. I have printed `$program_owner_id`

> Undefined variable: project_owner_id

```
<?php
class userController extends Controller
{
  protected $program_owner_id = array (); //protected variable

  public function mappingUserToRequest() {
    print_r($program_owner_id)  //Expected to use here
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: We need more code to help you, because we don't know how your class is build. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Try `$this->program_owner_id`. BTW, next time please quote the entire error and show the code which resulted in the error in its contex (i.e. the class definition excluding any unrelated methods)

Comment: You have been a member long enough to know this is not a well asked question

Comment: And how to format code...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class attributes are accessible via `$this`:

```
var_dump($this->program_owner_id);
```

Don't forget the semicolons!

Comment: Please don't use `print_r` to dump data - in case of false or null You will get nothing printed which is misleading in some cases. `var_dump` - this will give You all expected information.